# Is there a better way to verify that one looped list is contained in another in Java?

Tags: java

I am struggling to get the desired result when verifying to see if one list is contained in the other. I am not too sure how to handle it.

List 1:

```
 List<WebElement> allValues = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='allvalues']"));
    
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (WebElement all:allValues) {
          String s = all.getText().trim();
          list1.add(s);
        }
System.out.println(list1)
```

output:

```
"demo1", "demo2", "demo3", "demo4", "demo5"
```

List 2:

```
 List<WebElement> partValues= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='partvalues']"));
    List<String> list2= new ArrayList<>();
    
        for (WebElement part: partValues) {
          String t = part.getText().trim();
          list2.add(t);
        }
System.out.println(list2)
```

output:

```
"demo2", "demo3", "demo4"
```

I want to verify that list1 contains all of list 2. I tried a simple boolean verification method like:

`System.out.println(list1.containsAll(list2));` and `System.out.println(list2.containsAll(list1))`. Both returned false and that should not be te case.

What's the most reliable way to verify that `list1` contains `list2`?

Comment: `List.containsAll()` works as advertised.  It is the simplest way to determine whether all the elements in one list are also contained in the other, where elements are compared via their `equals(Object)` methods.  If you think it's not working for you, then this would be a good time to present a [mre] demonstrating that issue.

Answer (score 1):

[`List#containsAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)) works as documented, and does what you want.

I copy-pasted your example data.

```
List< String > list1 = List.of( "demo1", "demo2", "demo3", "demo4", "demo5" ) ;
List< String > list2 = List.of( "demo2", "demo3", "demo4" ) ;
boolean contained = list1.containsAll( list2 ) ;
```

See [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/414eiA).

> contained = true